# How to render a collection in jbuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, view, jbuilder

There is a fantastic method in Rails to render a collection of objects for view templates, and it works as fellows:

```
<%= render @restaurants %>
```

It's automatically gonna look for a partial named `_restaurant.html.erb`, loop through collection, pass individual object to the partial, and render it. This is pretty fantastic.

Now, I'm looking for a very similar way in `jbuilder` gem.

**_restaurant.json.jbuilder**

```
json.(restaurant, :id, :name, :address, :latitude, :longitude)
```

Now, for `@restaurants`, how would I use this partial in the same way it works in Rails for view templates? For the time being, I'm rendering the collection the following way:

```
json.restaurants @restaurants do |restaurant|
  json.partial! restaurant
end
```

Comment: Look what DHH's [comment](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/39#issuecomment-9148313) :p

Comment: But `json.partial! "restaurant", :collection => @restaurants` is good too.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Post your second comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think you are looking for the below :

```
json.partial! :restaurant, collection: @restaurants
```

Comment: I wonder how this can be a correct answer? It's only rendering one restaurant, isn't it?

Comment: I agree. This cannot be a correct answer since this way it's gonna render just one restaurant.

Comment: @Repolês @kangkyu No it will not render just one, look how [`collection:`](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/b952ae096eb1828b0fcfde06e6ba62311494ec49/README.md#L168) works.

Comment: Hey, @ArupRakshit. It does not work for me, really. The Rails log indeed says "Rendered collection of ...", but the resulting JSON includes just the first item of the collection. It's weird and I don't know if it's a bug with my Rails version or something I'm doing wrong. I can only output the collection when I use `json.array!`.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest I could find:

```rb
json.restaurants @restaurants, partial: 'restaurants/restaurant', as: :restaurant
```

...but is not really like rendering a collection of view partials (in the logs it still shows as multiple renders), and I dislike using the word 'restaurant' 5 times in a line of code